# formatting with printf while printing an array object

Tags: java, string, printing

I was wondering if you could do the following:

```
System.out.printf("%10.2f", car[i]);
```

Considering that I have redefined the `toString()` method.

```
public void toString() {
    return this.getPrice + "" + this.getBrandName;
}
```

Otherwise how do you format the price you print?

Answer (score 1):

Since `toString()` returns a `String`, you can format the printed object with `%s` ([see this](http://ideone.com/7isknn)) but not `%f` ([see this](http://ideone.com/Czly59)).

You can get the price as a float and print the formatted number along with the brand:

```
class Car {
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a car";
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return 20000.223214;
    }
    public String getBrandName() {
        return "Brand";
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c = new Car();
        System.out.printf("%10.2f %s", c.getPrice(), c.getBrandName());
    }
}
```

Output

```
  20000.22 Brand
```

(Represent the price in cents if it's easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead.

```
public void toString() {
    return String.format("%10.2f", this.getPrice) + "" + this.getBrandName;
}
```